# External monitor refresh rates with laptops with nvidia GPUs

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, display, displayport, integrated-graphics

So, I'm considering buying an external monitor to use alongside my laptop.
My laptop has a GTX 970M, and an i7 6700-HQ (with integrated Intel HD Graphics 530).

This monitor would be 120/144hz capable. My laptop's built in screen is only 60hz. If I wanted to switch between 60hz and 120/144hz modes for different games (because I get different frame rates in different games). Firstly, would it be possible?

Second, if yes, it would have to be through the Intel HD Graphics control panel that I change this (because I only have access to 3D Settings through the Nvidia Control Panel). Would this still affect the refresh rate of the monitor when using the GPU?

I couldn't find much definitive information elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Windows 10 users :

Right click the desktop, click Display Settings and click "Advanced Display Settings". Once you're there, click on display adapter propeties and click on the "Monitor" Tab.

For Windows 7 users :

Right click the desktop, click Screen Resolution and then click on "Advanced Settings" and click the Monitor Tab.

Comment: There is no Appearance and Themes in the control panel for me (when displayed as icons nor category), and the only properties I get when clicking on the desktop are the Intel HD Graphics properties, which then does not have tabs as you described. Even if it did, it fails to answer my second question. More information required;

Comment: @Matthew I updated the question, hope it helped.

Comment: And that will change the refresh rate system-wide, independent and regardless of whether I'm using the GPU or integrated graphics at the time?

Comment: @Matthew Yes.  .